# How do you interface with this sensor? MPS-2100series

Tags: sensor, resistor-ladder

I am trying to figure out how to get a reading from this sensor. At first look at the schematic, it thought it was wheatstone bridge, but at a closer look, it appears to be a resistor ladder type circuit, but I don't understand what it is doing.

Can someone fill me in?

http://www.metrodyne.com.tw/datasheets/en/MPS/MPS-2100series.pdf

Thank you

Comment: I would tie pins 1 & 6 together and treat it as a bridge.

Comment: Maybe googling "strain gauge" can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it is a Wheatstone Bridge circuit. There are many ways of interfacing a bridge circuit like this. For example, using a differential op-amp circuit to create a representative voltage, or connecting the differential pins to two inputs of a microcontroller and doing the differential calculation from the ADC values.